# Correction factor In permutation and combination

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So It's always confusing for me where to apply the correction factor in permutation and combination. For example there is a question like find the number of ways in which 4 distinct object can be divided into 2 groups such that one group has 2 objects and other group has 2 objects. Can someone explain me how to apply correction factor to this question
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether the groups are **labelled** or **unlabeled**

Suppose you have $4$ objects, $A,B,C,D$ to be divided into two equal groups.

The first group can be formed in $\binom42$ = $6$ ways

Now if the groups are labelled, say East and West, there will actually be $6$ possible groups of two, but see what happens when they are unlabeled !

$AB-CD$ becomes the same as $CD-AB$, so you need to divide the result by $2$, or more correctly, by $2!$

If you wanted to form three groups of $2$ from $6$ objects, the number of unlabeled groups would be $[\binom62\binom42\binom22] \div 3!$

*Note that groups can get automatically labelled by differing size, or differing type (e.g. gender)*

---

**Response to OP's comment**

Labelled = named, or distinguishable

Unlabeled = unnamed, or indistinguishable

So if from $4$ objects you make two groups of two, if the groups are labeled Eat and West, groups are

EAST WEST
$AB\quad CD$
$AC\quad BD$
$AD\quad BC$
$BC\quad AD$
$BD\quad AD$
$CD\quad AB$ .... $6$ labelled groups

But if they are unlabeled, how can we distinguish between $AB\;CD$ and $CD\;AB$ and so on, so now only three unlabeled groups can be formed,
$AB\quad CD$
$AC\quad BD\;$
$AD\quad BC$

Comment: Sir Can you please explain the concept of labelled and unlabeled more strongly as I got a little bit of idea of your answer but this labelled and unlabeled concept is still confusing. I would be grateful if you do so

Comment: @πααρτθΣαρθι *Labeled* and *Unlabeled* represent the concise mathematical terms used to determine whether Group-1 and Group-2 (for example) are distinguishable from each other.  That is, suppose Person-1 is partnered with Person-2.  Is Group-1 = [Person-1:Person-2] to be considered the same as, or different from Group-2 = [Person-1:Person-2]?  If Group-1 and Group-2 are **unlabeled**, then the two possibilities are considered the same.  Alternatively, if Group-1 and Group-2 are **labeled**, then the two possibilities are considered **distinct** from each other.

Comment: I have added further explanation.

Comment: Oh, my friend @user2661923 has meanwhile also explained. You should now be crystal clear. The concept is very important in avoiding undercount/overcount.

Comment: @trueblueanil Sir I think the last example must be AD AND BC as you have written AD AND BD.

Comment: @user2661923 Finally my doubt is cleared with proper examples thank you sir :)

Comment: @trueblueanil Thank you sir for clearing my concept as I don't have much of the reputation I am not able to upvote .

Comment: No sweat, glad to be of help !$\;\;$ :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140999/discussion-between---and-true-blue-anil).

Comment: Sorry, I don't chat. However, you should be able to see that, say when computing probability, $\frac{\binom42}{\binom62}$ (combination approach) is the same as $\frac{4\times3}{6\times 5}$ (permutation approach) Counting the sample space, (more precisely **points** in the sample space) would be $4\times3$ and $6\times5$ respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the two groups are to be regarded as indistinguishable, the enumeration of $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} = 6~$ is wrong.

Consider the grouping:

- Group-1 : Person-1, Person-2
- Group-2 : Person-3, Person-4

Now, consider the **associated** grouping:

- Group-1 : Person-3, Person-4
- Group-2 : Person-1, Person-2

If the two groupings are to be considered the same, then you have a problem, because in the $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}~$ enumeration, they are counted twice.  You will have the same over-counting for any other grouping.

So, the correct enumeration, when Group-1 and Group-2 are to be regarded as **indistinguishable** from each other is

$$\binom{4}{2} \times \frac{1}{2!}.$$

---

An alternative viewpoint is to ask, who will Person-1 be grouped with.  There are only $3$ choices, and once Person-1's partner has been chosen, the groupings are set.

This assumes that it is irrelevant whether Person-1 and their partner are chosen in Group-1 or Group-2.

Comment: thanks alot sir :)))

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication principle applies when counting *lists*, and lists have a distinct order to them. But sometimes we are counting objects for which certain orderings/rearrangements aren't important. In these situations, we divide the total number of lists by the number of rearrangements which are to be considered “equivalent."

In your example, let the four objects be numbered as 1, 2, 3, 4. To partition them into two sets of two elements, we can:

1. start with a list of the four objects
2. take the first pair and assign them to the first set
3. take the second pair and assign them to the second set.

So if the list is $(1,4,3,2)$, the associated partition is $\{\{1,4\},\{3,2\}\}$.

There are $4! = 24$ lists of the four objects, so you have at most $24$ partitions. However, this process will result in many lists generating the same partition! For instance, $(4,1,3,2)$, $(1,4,2,3)$, and $(2,3,4,1)$ will all generate the same partition as $(1,4,3,2)$. This is because lists are ordered and sets are not.

So the next thing to count is *how many* lists generate the same partition. Given any list $(a,b,c,d)$, these are the lists which generate the same set $\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$:
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
    (a,b,c,d) & (b,a,c,d) & (a,b,d,c) & (b,a,d,c) \\
    (c,d,a,b) & (c,d,b,a) & (d,c,a,b) & (d,c,b,a) 
\end{array}$$

Another solution to this question: notice that there are three permutations of the list elements that don't affect the associated partition:

- swapping the first pair: $(a,b,c,d) \mapsto (b,a,c,d)$ [because $\{b,a\} = \{a,b\}$, so $\{\{b,a\},\{c,d\}\} = \{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$]
- swapping the second pair: $(a,b,c,d) \mapsto (a,b,d,c)$
- swapping the two pairs: $(a,b,c,d) \mapsto (c,d,a,b)$

We can do any combination of these three permutations too. Swap first and second, swap first then the two pairs, all three swaps, etc.
So the number of lists equivalent to any one list (including the one we started with) is $2 \times 2 \times 2 = 8$.

Putting this together: the $24$ lists are divided into groups of $8$. Each group corresponds to one and only one partition. So the number of partitions equals the number of groups. That is, $24 \div 8 = 3$.

If you let go of “permutations and combinations” and think instead about equivalences on sets of lists, you can solve more problems.

Comment: thank alot sir for making me learn a new concept of equivalences will work on it or sure

Comment: Sir sorry to bother you but can you explain your steps again where you are swapping I actually didn't got it.

Comment: and how did you perform the combination of those 3 permutation ? :)

Comment: @πααρτθΣαρθι I have added some details.

Comment: Sir if we had to do the same question with3 groups each with 2 objects how to find the no of list that will generate same partition (thanks alot)

Comment: In that case, you can swap each pair, and permute the three pairs, so there are $2^3 \times 3!$ lists which generate the same partition.

Comment: the answer would be 15. So this means we can make 15 different pairs of different objects ?

Comment: does it mean  (1,3) (2,4) (5,6) can make 1 group and (1,5) (2,6) ( 3,4) make 2nd group and so on ? till 15

Comment: Yes, I got $6!/(2^3 \times 3!) = 15$ as well.

Comment: does it mean (1,3) (2,4) (5,6) can make 1 group and (1,5) (2,6) ( 3,4) make 2nd group and so on ? till 15